# Job Scheduling Table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to run jobs based on a schedule using windows service.
But I need to save the schedules in database. Can anyone suggest the table structure to store Schedules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089431/database-table-design-for-scheduling-tasks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database table design for scheduling tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089431/database-table-design-for-scheduling-tasks)